# ngTagsInput - only allow selection of autocomplete suggestions?

Tags: angularjs, ng-tags-input

If you are pulling from a source of

[{text: 'a'}, {text: 'ab'}, {text: 'abc'}]

and user enters in 'abcd', how do you prevent user from creating an 'abcd' tag?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just set the `addFromAutocompleteOnly` to `true` and only suggestions coming from the autocomplete popup will be allowed to be added as tags.

```
<tags-input ng-model="tags" add-from-autocomplete-only="true">
  <auto-complete source="loadTags($query)"></auto-complete>
</tags-input>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BrXowqBpABsZKNIZ9EQp?p=preview)